# How can I get List of objects with Generic type in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010

I have several classes as follows:

```
Type
  TSystemBaseEntity = class(TPersistent)
  private 
    FID: integer;
  public
    property ID: integer read FID write FID;
  end;

  TProcessHeaderEntity = class(TSystemBaseEntity)
  private
    FHeaderDate: TDateTime;
  public
     property HeaderDate: TDateTime read FHeaderDate write FHeaderDate;
  end;

  TInvoiceHeaderEntity = class(TProcessHeaderEntity)
  private 
    FCustomerId: integer;
  public
    property CustomerId: integer read FCustomerId write FCustomerId;
  end;


  TRequestHeaderEntity = class(TProcessHeaderEntity)
  private 
    FWarehouseId: integer;
  public
    property WarehouseId: integer read FWarehouseId write FWarehouseId;
  end;


  TDataList = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FValues: TObjectList<TSystemBaseEntity>;
  protected
    function SetCaption: string; virtual;
  public
    procedure Execute; virtual; abstract;
    property Values: TObjectList<TSystemBaseEntity> read FValues;
  end;

  TInvoice = class(TDataList)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;
```

How can I get list of objects with generic types that inherited from **TSystemBaseEntity**  by **Values** property?

For example, a list of Invoices(TInvoiceHeaderEntity) or a list of Requests(TRequestHeaderEntity) and access to it's properties.

Comment: There's no built-in way to filter a list by the type of its contents, if that's what you're asking. If that's not what you're asking, then I'm not sure what your obstacle is.

Comment: How can you get a list? Get it from where? What is your input?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I need to have a list of the type that by passing a type(e.g TInvoiceHeaderEntity ) TDataList will give me a list of

Comment: Please read my comment again and try to address the questions I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a TDataList that holds one specific subclass of TSystemBaseEntity, define TDataList to be a generic class, with a [type constraint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Constraints_in_Generics)

This is defined as

```
  TDataList<T:TSystemBaseEntity> = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FValues: TObjectList<T>;
  protected
    function SetCaption: string; virtual;
  public
    procedure Execute; virtual; abstract;
    property Values: TObjectList<T> read FValues;
  end;
```

And used as

```
  TInvoice = class(TDataList<TInvoiceHeaderEntity>)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TInvoice.Execute
var
  InvoiceHeader: TInvoiceHeaderEntity;
begin
  for InvoiceHeader in Values do
    ...
end;
```

If you instead want one type TDataList, with a member that is `TObjectList<TSystemBaseEntity>`, you cannot use that as a `TObjectList<TInvoiceHeaderEntity>` etc. Have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) for an introduction, but also consider the following would be allowed under such a scheme:

```
procedure DoBadThingsWithGenerics(aDataList: TDataList);
var
  myInvoices: TObjectList<TInvoiceHeaderEntity>
  myRequests: TObjectList<TRequestHeaderEntity>
  Request: TRequestHeaderEntity;
begin
  myInvoices := aDataList.Values<TInvoiceHeaderEntity>;
  myRequests := aDataList.Values<TRequestHeaderEntity>;

  // Some code ...

  myInvoices.Add( TInvoiceHeaderEntity.Create );

  // Some more code...

  for Request in myRequests do
    // Oops, we have a TInvoiceHeaderEntity pretending to be a TRequestHeaderEntity
end;
```

What you can do here is have a procedure that takes a new list of the decendant type, filtering elements of the Values list that are of the appropriate type and adding them to the new list.

```
procedure TDataList.FilterByType<S:TSystemBaseEntity> ( intoList: TObjectList<S> );
var
  Value: TSystemBaseEntity;
begin
  for Value in Values do
    if Value is S then
      intoList.Add( Value as S );
end;
```

Comment: I want Values be a generic class and passing a type to it then get Values as this passed type.

Comment: Are you asking for a non-generic TDataList with a generic property Values? something like "property Values<T>: TObjectList<T>"? Delphi doesn't support that. TInvoice above will let you use members declared in TInvoiceHeaderEntity with the elements of its Values property

Comment: Can you clarify which part of my answer is what you were after?

Comment: I've used the first part: TInvoice = class(TDataList<TInvoiceHeaderEntity>)